# Is there any example of linear operator which is bounded on all Besov spaces but not on Triebel-Lizorkin spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, function-spaces, besov-spaces

Is there any linear operator $T:S'(\mathbb R^n)\to S'(\mathbb R^n)$ such that $T:B_{pq}^s(\mathbb R^n)\to B_{pq}^s(\mathbb R^n)$ for all $0<p,q\le\infty$ and $s\in\mathbb R$, but there exist a $F_{pq}^s$ such that $T(F_{pq}^s(\mathbb R^n))\not\subset F_{pq}^s(\mathbb R^n)$?

Note that the real interpolation $(F_{p,q_0}^{s_0},F_{p,q_1}^{s_1})_{\theta,q}=B_{p,q}^{s_\theta}$ says that if an operator is bounded on all Triebel-Lizorkin spaces then by interpolation it will be bounded on Besov spaces as well. That is also the reason that many paper only prove the case of Triebel-Lizorkin and omit the Besov cases.

The reverse direction always haunt me as it does not seem to have an interpolation techniques that sends Besov to Triebel-Lizorkin.